# Laravel eloquent where Or where with belongsToMany

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Today I can across something I was'nt expecting

```
namespace App\Models;



use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class News extends Model
{
protected $table="news";


public function media(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Media::class, "news_medias");
}

}
```

This is my News Model

```
News::find(20)->media()->where("medias.id",36)->orWhere("medias.type",1)->get()
```

When making this call, I am expecting to search for a Media that has an ID of 36 or media with a type of 1 with in the medias connected to the news with an ID of 20.

```
SELECT `medias`.*, `news_medias`.`news_id` as `pivot_news_id`, `news_medias`.`media_id` as `pivot_media_id` 
FROM `medias` inner join `news_medias` on `medias`.`id` = `news_medias`.`media_id` 
WHERE `news_medias`.`news_id` = 20 and `medias`.`id` = 36 or `medias`.`type` = 1
```

this is what the query log gives me, and this doesnt seem right, since  it should be

```
SELECT `medias`.*, `news_medias`.`news_id` as `pivot_news_id`, `news_medias`.`media_id` as `pivot_media_id` 
FROM `medias` inner join `news_medias` on `medias`.`id` = `news_medias`.`media_id` 
WHERE `news_medias`.`news_id` = 20 and (`medias`.`id` = 36 or `medias`.`type` = 1)
```

My version of  is Laravel 5.6

Or am I getting this wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
News::find(20)->media()->where(function ($q) {
    $q->where("id",36)->orWhere("type",1);
})->get();
```

Eloquent doesn't add the parenthesis when using the orWhere operator, you need to create a subquery for the desired result

Comment: And there is no way to avoid this, right? Shouldnt using a a belogsToMany automaticly do this?

Comment: I honestly don't know a way to avoid this, it is an internal behaviour of Eloquent.

Answer (score 1):

Give this query a try:

```
News::with(["media" => function($query){
  $query->where("medias.id", "=", 36)->orWhere("medias.type", "=", 1);
}])->find(20)->media;
```

What this does is query `news` while also querying the `media` relationship for any `medias` records where `id` is 36 or `type` is 1. Then, using `->find(20)` would return your `News` model, and accessing `->media` would return the collection constrained to your parameters in the `->with()` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your query to the following:

```
Media::where('id',1)
     ->orWhere(function($query) {
           $query->where('type',1)
                ->whereHas('news', function($q) {
                    $q->where('id',20);
                 };
      })->get();
```

It basically searches for medias with id one, or for the medias with type 1 and is connected to news with id 20